# How query with data functions in group by ca be optimized

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, query-optimization

i have a query as given below

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( f.receipt_date ) AS MONTH , 
SUM( CASE WHEN fm.fee_name =  'University Fees' THEN f.fee_amount END ) AS A
FROM fee_type_masters fm
INNER JOIN student_fee_collections f ON fm.id = f.fee_type
GROUP BY MONTH( f.receipt_date )
```

and my tables are like

```
CREATE TABLE `fee_type_masters` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fee_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fee_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `year` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `student_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `due_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
 `accounts_master_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `comments` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `sem` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `degree_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `approve_needed` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `concession_allowed` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `relation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `student_fee_collections` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fee_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fee_amount` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `due` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `received` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `concession` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `receipt_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `receipt_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `received_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `amount` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `late_fee` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `pay_mode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `comments` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `student_id` (`fee_type`,`student_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=325 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

each is having more than 20000 rows

and my explain plan is like

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  fm  ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    7000    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  f   ref student_id  student_id  5   emsnew.fm.id    28000   Using where
```

any one please tell me how to optimize the query or rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Create Index on **fee_type** column in **student_fee_collections** and recheck the output of **Explain Query**. And update the same in your question.

Comment: already i have the index on that............index(a,b) means index(a) and index(a,b) right?    if not please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Create **Index** on **fee_type** column in **student_fee_colle**

and run the following query

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( f.receipt_date ) AS MONTH , 
SUM( CASE WHEN fm.fee_name =  'University Fees' THEN f.fee_amount END ) AS A
FROM fee_type_masters fm
INNER JOIN student_fee_collections f USE index(fee_type_IDX) ON fm.id = f.fee_type
GROUP BY MONTH( f.receipt_date )
```